# python math, numpy modules different results?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I get slightly different results calculating the cosine of a value. How can I check that this difference is within machine precision?

```
import math
math.cos(60.0/180.0*math.pi)
-> 0.5000000000000001

import numpy
numpy.cos(60.0/180.0*numpy.pi)
-> 0.50000000000000011
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference seems to be caused by the formatting routines only:

```
>>> '%.30f' % math.cos(60./180.*math.pi)
'0.500000000000000111022302462516'
>>> '%.30f' % np.cos(60./180.*np.pi)
'0.500000000000000111022302462516'
```

Note that `np.cos` returns `np.float64` rather than `float`, and apparently that type is printed differently by default. On common hardware, they're both implemented as 64-bit `double`, so there's no actual difference in precision.

Comment: `np.float64` and `float` will be backed by the same IEEE-754 double precision data type

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yep, just not the same `__repr__`, apparently.

Comment: Of course what you point out in your answer is useful I think it's also useful to have a feel for how much precision you have in a double value. You can actually answer all of this question without running any code and instead just counting digits.

Answer (score 5):

[Double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) arithmetic gives you precision of 15-16 decimal significant figures. These two values agree to that precision. Nothing worry about here.

Note that I say *decimal* to contrast with the 53 *binary* bits used for the significand in the binary representation of a double precision value.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was there at the cusp of double-precision accuracy!

Comment: That's odd because that was exactly the question you asked, "How can I check that this difference is within machine
precision?" which is what I tried to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Eventhough your numbers turned out to be equal, it is still useful to know how to examine them at full precision.  Here are a couple of ways to do it:

```
>>> a = 1.1 + 2.2
>>> b = 3.3
>>> a == b
False
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal.from_float(a)
Decimal('3.300000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875')
>>> Decimal.from_float(b)
Decimal('3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875')
>>> a.hex()
'0x1.a666666666667p+1'
>>> b.hex()
'0x1.a666666666666p+1'
>>> a.as_integer_ratio()
(7430939385161319, 2251799813685248)
>>> b.as_integer_ratio()
(3715469692580659, 1125899906842624)
```

Comment: Great, this is a good way to check. In `R` there is a variable called `.Machine$double.eps` and `.Machine$double.neg.eps` which can be used to set tolerances, but these tests are also helpful...

Comment: Or even just `Decimal(a)`;  no need for the `from_float` method.