# complex-valued math evaluations permitted in Python but not in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is this documented anywhere? Why such a drastic difference?

```
# Python 3.2
# numpy 1.6.2 using Intel's Math Kernel Library
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.float64(-0.2)
>>> x ** 0.8
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
nan
>>> x = -0.2 # note: `np.float` is same built-in `float`
>>> x ** 0.8
(-0.2232449487530631+0.16219694943147778j)
```

This is especially confusing since [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7825588/336527), `np.float64` and built-in `float` are identical except for `__repr__`.

I can see how the warning from `np` may be useful in some cases (especially since it can be disabled or enabled in `np.seterr`); but the problem is that the return value is `nan` rather than the complex value provided by the built-in. Therefore, this breaks code when you start using `numpy` for some of the calculations, and don't convert its return values to built-in float explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.float` may or may not be `float`, but complex numbers are not `float` at all:

```
In [1]: type((-0.2)**0.8)
Out[1]: builtins.complex
```

So there's no `float` result of the operation, hence `nan`.

If you don't want to do an explicit conversion to `float` (which is [recommended](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars)), do the `numpy` calculation in complex numbers:

```
In [3]: np.complex(-0.2)**0.8
Out[3]: (-0.2232449487530631+0.16219694943147778j)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your argument? There's nothing that prevents a binary operation on floats from returning a complex number. As indeed is shown by the behavior of built-in Python.

Comment: @max Right. I think the reason behind this is that if you have an array of positive and negative floats and then do something like `arr**0.8`, then the complex numbers won't fit in a float array. `numpy` doesn't like unhomogeneous sequences. So maybe this is implemented this way for consistency with the case of arrays.

Comment: A couple of comments... The behavior of (-0.2)**0.8 changed between Python 2.x and 3.x. In 2.x, that expression returns a ValueError. Also, an np.float64 is not identical to a Python float. Behind the scenes, they both use 64-bit IEEE-754 entities but they are different Python objects.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of returning a complex number from a float operation is certainly not usual, and was only introduced with Python 3 (like the float division of integers with the `/` operator). In Python 2.7 you get the following:

```
In [1]: (-0.2)**0.8
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

On a scalar, if instead of `np.float64` you use `np.float`, you'll get the same `float` type as Python uses. (And you'll either get the above error in 2.7 or the complex number in 3.x.)

For arrays, all the numpy operators return the same type of array, and most ufuncs do not support casting from float > complex (e.g., check `np.<ufunc>.type`).

- If what you want is a consistent operation on scalars, use `np.float`
- If you are interested in array operations, you'll have to cast the array as complex: `x = x.astype('complex')`